# File weird character encoding

Tags: files, character-encoding

I'm on ubuntu 13.10 and am writing a program in eclipse that's supposed to output my result in a file. I'm building an LZW compression and decompression program that uses character conversion to its code. On console everything outputs fine. But when I try to redirect the output to a file (something.txt), all am getting is something like this:

> 扡聡膀蚃膂詢誋

{EDIT}

cat somthing.txt shows the following:

> aba�������b���

`locale` says:

> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   LANGUAGE=en_US:en
>   LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
>   LC_ALL=

where ababbababaaab is the input of my program and the output should be the ascii numbers of some of these characters

I tried to change the encoding from terminal but nothing changed. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: What does `locale` say? What does `your-program | hexdump -C` say? How do you view the file? E.g. what does `cat something.txt` show you on the console?

Comment: @9000 I editted it.

Comment: My suspicion is that you are not writing the repeat counts as numbers (`printf("%d", count)`), but write them as naked bytes. Try the `| hexdump -C` thing and check what characters come after `aba`.

Comment: How should we know? Your program's output isn't what you expect, but you haven't shown us your program's code.

Comment: @Gilles I was writing on a file in a way that outputed right while trying it on Windows. It's ubuntu default files encoding or sometihng that caused the weird characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem disappeared using `PrintWriter` and setting its parameter to `UTF-8` instead of `DataOutputStream` while writing on my file. (Java)